# SQL LIKE this OR that

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**I'm trying to do:** 
(i'm working with codeignitor)

```
$conditions = $tri." LIKE'%".$prenomNom."%' OR LIKE'%".$nomPrenom."%'";
```

**I also tried:**

```
$conditions = ($tri." LIKE '%".$prenomNom."%' OR ".$tri." LIKE '%".$nomPrenom."%'");
```

But the OR doesn't work... my request return only $tri like $nameLastname.

When i do echo of $nameLastname and $LastnameName everything is ok.

**My code**

```
  public function rechercheParAuteur($selection = "*", $recherche = "", $tri = "", $champs_order = "id", $direction_ordre = "ASC", $nombre_limite = NULL, $debut_limite = NULL){   
  //$conditions = "titre LIKE '%".$recherche."%'"; //création de la condition personnalisée
  $testrecherche = str_replace("'","\'", $recherche);
  $rechercheArray = explode(" ", $testrecherche);
  if (isset($rechercheArray[1])) 
  {
    $nomPrenom = $rechercheArray[0]." ".$rechercheArray[1];
    $prenomNom = $rechercheArray[1]." ".$rechercheArray[0]; 
    //$conditions = $tri." LIKE'%".$prenomNom."%' OR LIKE'%".$nomPrenom."%'"; 
    $conditions = ($tri." LIKE '%".$prenomNom."%' OR ".$tri." LIKE '%".$nomPrenom."%'"); 
    //echo $nomPrenom; OK
    //echo $prenomNom; OK
  }
  else
  {   
    $resultat = $rechercheArray[0];      
    $conditions = $tri." LIKE '%".$resultat."%'"; 
  }

  $retour= $this->db->select($selection)
      /*à partir de quelle table*/
      ->from($this->table)
      /*déterminer des conditions spécifiques*/
      ->where($conditions)
      /*déterminer un ordre précis*/
      ->order_by($champs_order, $direction_ordre)
      /*déterminer une limite*/
      ->limit($nombre_limite, $debut_limite)
      /*obtenir les résultats (va de pair avec result()*/
      ->get()
      /*retourner les résultats sous forme de tableau*/
      ->result_array();

      return $retour;
```

Comment: try to echo your final query and figure out what's wrong.

Comment: it throw error or wrong result...!?

Comment: I echo them and it's ok...

Comment: What is the full query you have? You need to specify the contents of `$tri`

Comment: $tri is ok, there is no sql error. i'll put my full query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to put the condition in perens.

```
$conditions = "($tri LIKE '%$prenomNom%' OR $tri LIKE '%$nomPrenom%')";
```